# in need of a simple example that shows serverside python program passing data to webserver

Tags: python

are there any simple examples you know of that demonstrate how a python program can pass data to a webserver? ive been looking for so long but i still cannot find any. something simple will do. say for example, a python program that generates some text or number that the webserver accepts and updates a field in a local site with. thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking the easiest way to do this would be with [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html).

Depending on what exactly you mean by "updates a field in a local site" you probably either want to send data in a GET or POST variable.  Below are examples of doing each:

GET request:

```
import urllib2

response = urllib2.urlopen('http://example.com/some/path/?myvar=myvalue')
```

POST request:

```
import urlib2

response = urllib2.urlopen('http://example.com/some/path/', {'myvar': 'myvalue'})
```

The response object you get back is a file like object.  Accordingly if you want to get the string contents of the response, you can simply call `response.read()` or if you want to look at the metadata of the response (e.g. headers, http status code, etc) you can call the `response.info()` method.

Finally a bit of advice for future, similar searches you probably will have more luck using the terminology "how to make an HTTP request with python" instead of "how to pass data to a webserver in python".  You will generally get much better results looking for details on how to accomplish a specific action action as opposed to a more general goal.

Comment: thanks for the reply sir. im running on apache webserver and plan to use GET. can you please show please add a few more lines and what also show what the html file would look like?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your question.  Are you looking to have the script send data to the server, or are you looking to have the script serve a form and then accept the input from that form?

Comment: i am very sorry i did not phrase the question right. let me be very honest here, the end is to display images based on python data. so on the same computer i have my webserver in, i have a python program that will generate a number continuously from 1-10 every 2 seconds. what i want to happen is to take this this number from the python program and somehow pass this to the website. that is why i am looking for a simple example so that i can understand the basics of how this works

Comment: That's going to be kinda tricky and the best solutions is going to depend on what exactly the python program is doing and how much control you have over the web application.

In the simplest case you want to setup a URL on your web application expecting input from your program and then you can use the code above to call the server from your program.  How to setup the web server side of things will entirely depend on what you're running as your web server/application.

Comment: Alternatively, it might make more sense to have a library to do what your program is doing and call that from your web application directly.  Depending on what the python program is doing, you can probably figure out the "current" number based on the computer's clock instead of having a program running continuously.  If this option can work it would be much more simple, efficient, and stable.